# I have both its private key and its certificate, which I want to use in JMETER recording proxy instead of the default certificate. How can I do that?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I have an application that requires a specific server certificate to work. So, I have both its private key and its certificate, which I want to use in JMETER recording proxy instead of the default certificate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are following properties which you can use to configure JMeter to use your own certificate:

```
proxy.cert.directory=<JMeter bin directory>
proxy.cert.file=proxyserver.jks
proxy.cert.type=JKS
proxy.cert.keystorepass=password
proxy.cert.keypassword=password
proxy.cert.factory=SunX509
```

If you want to override them - define your own values in *user.properties* file in JMeter's "bin" folder.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Test Script Recorder certificate configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)